# Header inside a header? (HTML5)

Tags: html

This seems strange to me but oddly there is a reason to use a `<header>` inside a `<header>`.

With the [`<hgroup>` remove from the spec](http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/) I'm seem to be at a weird state with what I should/could be doing with a following bit of code.

```
<header>
    <header>
        <h1>Maecenas faucibus</h1>
        <p class="h1-sub">Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </header>
    <section>
        <img src="..." alt="faucibus">
        <img src="..." alt="faucibus">
        <img src="..." alt="faucibus">
    </section>
</header>
```

This does all appear in the header portion of an `<article>` so I wonder if it does visually appear there then should I still define it as a `<header>` or should I wrap it all in something like:

```
<section class="article-header">
    <header><h1>...</h1><p>...</p></header>
    <section>...</section>
</section>
```

I've not come across anything that said `<header>` couldn't be nesting inside itself and wondered if this was the same call where you can have `<article>` nested in itself if it made logical sense (so if something is grouped together makes sense but also still does by itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [**HTML5 specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html), it is **invalid** to have a `<header>` element inside another `<header>` element.

It's interesting, because the `<header>` permitted contents technically do allow for it:

> Permitted contents `->` Flow content `->` Flow elements `->` Header

**However**, there are constraints which are specific to the `<header>` element - they include:

> - The header element must not appear as a descendant of the footer
>     element.
> - The header element must not appear as a descendant of the  address
>     element.
> - **The header element must not appear as a descendant of the header element.**

Therefore it is **not** valid mark-up - either as a direct child element or as a descendant element at all.

Comment: Nowadays, it's worth to mention, that `header` can be nested, as long as the parent is _sectioning content_. See [W3C HTML 5.2 - header element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#the-header-element) and there [Example 20](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#example-6f9fce34)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the link to the HTML5 specification you just posted (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html) it says..

"The header element must not appear as a descendant of the header element."

Therefore according to the specification it contains flow content but excluding header, footer or main elements.